# Fantasy book, questing boy with wolf cub companion?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can't remember the name of this book about a person who is either on some sort of quest or is running from something. He discovers a wolf cub along the way (I think its mom had just died in a storm or something) and it becomes a traveling companion. I think I can remember him saying, or thinking, something like it would help him survive because the cub with its nose could pick up scents and sense threats before he could or something.

I think there was a fight with like a gigantic bear at some point and also at another point in the book I think he almost drowned because a evil hand tried to pull him underwater or something?

I think I read the book like a decade or so ago, does anyone know what this is?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4):

I just remembered, It was [Michelle Paver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelle_Paver)'s [Chronicles of Ancient Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Ancient_Darkness), specifically [Wolf Brother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Ancient_Darkness#Wolf_Brother) and [Soul Eater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Ancient_Darkness#Soul_Eater) (I think).

> The books chronicle the adventures of Torak, an adolescent boy, and
>   his friends Renn and Wolf. The main story arc revolves around Torak
>   and his quest to defeat the Soul Eaters, a group of power hungry mages
>   who seek out to destroy all life in the forest.

Comment: You will be able to accept your answer in about 43 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.